# Can't configure hibernate when using rest services

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I have a project that work on a classic server-client using spring, but it isn't working with rest services.

In my Repo module i have the Utils class that initialize the session factory

```
package app.repos.db;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class Utils {

    protected static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected static void initialize() {
        // A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            System.out.println("BEGIN TRY !!");
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
            System.out.println("END TRY !!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }

    public static void close() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

and my hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!--         Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="domain/jurat.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="domain/participant.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="domain/rezultat.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The gradle from repos module:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project (':Domain')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.20.1'

    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0'

    implementation group: 'com.github.gwenn', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '0.1.0'

}
```

My rest controller is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app/rezultate")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    private RezultateRepoDB rezultate;
    @Autowired
    private JuratiRepoDB jurati;
    @Autowired
    private ParticipantiRepoDB participanti;

    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Participant[] getAll(){
        return participanti.findAll().toArray(new Participant[0]);
    }
}
```

When i call the getAll method i get an error in Utils at initialize method and i don't know what is wrong
Here are the console log

```
BEGIN TRY !!
2021-06-20 17:54:54.648  INFO 5944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2021-06-20 17:54:54.696 ERROR 5944 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataBuilderInitializer: Provider org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer could not be instantiated] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.dialect.identity.IdentityColumnSupportImpl: method 'void <init>()' not found
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport.<init>(SQLiteDialectIdentityColumnSupport.java:3) ~[sqlite-dialect-0.1.0.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect.<clinit>(SQLiteDialect.java:114) ~[sqlite-dialect-0.1.0.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer.<clinit>(SQLiteMetadataBuilderInitializer.java:28) ~[sqlite-dialect-0.1.0.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:782) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:724) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1396) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:324) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at app.repos.db.Utils.initialize(Utils.java:19) ~[Repos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at app.repos.db.JuratiRepoDB.findOne(JuratiRepoDB.java:29) ~[Repos-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at app.rest.AppController.getAll(AppController.java:37) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.14.jar:8.5.14]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your config or your code, but frankly, I haven't seen a Spring app use Hibernate directly, or configure it via a hibernate.cfg.xml in many years.

Try using SpringBoot and JPA, and use the annotation-based configuration options and spring's application.properties config file.

See for instance, https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/23/spring-tips-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Root cause from provided stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [app.repos.dialect.SQLiteDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

Please double-check that your SQLiteDialect class extends org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect and contains data about all needed mapping

Or you can try existing SQLiteDialect instead of having your custom one: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.dialect/sqlite-dialect/0.1.0

Comment: Yes, my SQLiteDialect class extends org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect. I also tried the dialect from your link but i can't find the SQLiteDialect class. Now i use this implementation group: 'com.github.gwenn', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '0.1.0' and i get NoSuchMethodError. I updated the log error and i also put my gradlle from repos module